# why Adobe Photoshop is required to tune a Web Templete

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver, photoshop

I am interested in working with some web templates such as the one mentioned here:-

[templete](http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/47767.html#tab-details)

but inside its details tab it is mentioned that the following software are required:-

- Adobe Photoshop CS+
- Sublime Text2 or later, Notepad++, Dreamweaver CS5.5+(Code mode only) or any php-editor

I am a web developer but not sure why i need to have all these software to be able to work with the template. So can i get answers to these questions:-

- Why i need adobe Photoshop CS+ ? now if i already have my website's pictures inside my machine, so do I need adobe Photoshop to work with the template ? or adobe Photoshop is required to work with the images rather than the web template itself. for example i will  need phtoshop if i want to minimize or change the contrast of an image , etc ?
- incase adobe Photoshop is required to be able to tune the web template or do extra features? do i need to purchase a licensed software or there is a free version of Photoshop that can satisfy this need?
- now as i know a web template will mainly contain css, html, script files. which can be edited and viewed by simple editor such as note pad  or by visual studio express . so if i have visual studio installed inside my machine do i still need ; Notepad++ , Dreamweaver or php-editor?
- now as i know web templates (without CMS) should work with any technology such as .net , php or other languages and can be deployed under iis, apache , etc. Now for the template linked above  will it only work on php ? because it is mentioned that i need php-editor to be able to work with the template?

Thanks in advance for any help.
John

Answer (score 1):

For your questions?

1. Why i need adobe Photoshop CS+ ? now if i already have my website's pictures inside my machine, so do I need adobe Photoshop to work with the template ? or adobe Photoshop is required to work with the images rather than the web template itself. for example i will need phtoshop if i want to minimize or change the contrast of an image , etc ?

No, you should not need to use photoshop cs+. If the template provider you mentioned above have photoshop source files provided, it will be easy for you to change colors, fonts, remove some layers, and yes if the contrast of the image if you do have photoshop. However, it is generally a job for a web designer. For re-sizing, not really. css can do. However a photoshop can do that better without losing resolution.

2. incase adobe Photoshop is required to be able to tune the web template or do extra features? do i need to purchase a licensed software or there is a free version of Photoshop that can satisfy this need?

there is photoshop trial version. There is also cs cloud trial version. I believe both are for 30 days. For simple photoshop editing, photoshop elements is much cheaper. cs cloud is subscription based, 19.99 dollars a month.

3. now as i know a web template will mainly contain css, html, script files. which can be edited and viewed by simple editor such as note pad or by visual studio express . so if i have visual studio installed inside my machine do i still need ; Notepad++ , Dreamweaver or php-editor?

No. Visual studio is enough. Though other editors, such as note pad, notepad++, etc. will do too. Note pad will be a nightmare though.

4. now as i know web templates (without CMS) should work with any technology such as .net , php or other languages and can be deployed under iis, apache , etc. Now for the template linked above will it only work on php ? because it is mentioned that i need php-editor to be able to work with the template?

Unless it has php server side code (their web forms are probably written in php)

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. but incase the template provides php forms ,, i can replace them with asp.net forms is this correct ? second question now i do not want to use adobe photoshop as we already have the images we want to upload ,, so in this case adobe photoshop is not needed ,, is this correct?

Comment: If your language of choice is asp .net, you should rewrite the php form using asp .net. Photoshop is completely for image editing, so if you do not need this editing capabilities, then should have no need for it. But must say, photoshop is a lot of fun :) and a lot of people buy those templates is because they would like have those professional images

Comment: thanks again for your reply. at the end i will be using asp.net to build the website functionalities. but i still need the html,css, javascrits from the template, so this should not be a problem, is this correct. so even if the web template forms are build using php i can rewrite them in asp.net and use the other web templates files? second point i know phtoshop is great tool but license is a problem in our case, but i was confused that in the template details they mentioned that we need Photoshop to work with the template,, so i though i will need it not only for editing pictures..

Comment: yes, html, css, javascripts are all for client side. it does not matter what server side language you use. i checked out the template site you provided, the source files they have are .psd and html files, the demo also seems that way. For the template .psd files, yes, you need photoshop to edit it. but if you have all of the images you need, then it should not  be needed. For html code, css, javascript, you can use any editor. Visual studio is always an excellent choice